# Write output from a loop to a csv

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have a script which predicts product names from input files. The code is as follows:

```
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\NER_training"
DIR = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\Testing\\'
print("Loading from", output_dir)
nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
with open('eng_productnames.csv', newline='') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    for rowz in reader:
        try:
            filenamez = rowz[1]
            file = open(DIR+filenamez, "r", encoding ='utf-8')
            filecontentszz = file.read()
            for s in filecontentszz:
                filecontentszz = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', filecontentszz)
                #filecontents = filecontents.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
                filecontentszz = ''.join([line.lower() for line in filecontentszz]) 
                doc2 = nlp2(filecontentszz)
                for ent in doc2.ents:
                    print(filenamez, ent.label_, ent.text)

                break

        except Exception as e:`
```

which gives me output in the form of a stringas:

```
07-09-18 N021024s16PASBUNDLEACK - Acknowledgement P.txt PRODUCT ABC1
06-22-18 Letter from Supl.txt PRODUCT ABC2
06-22-18 Letter from Req to Change .txt PRODUCT ABC3
```

Now I want to export all these details to a csv with 2 columns, one column as FILENAME and one column with PRODUCT having all filenames and product names under the respective column names. All product names start with PRODUCT and then the name in the string. How can I solve this:

Output csv should look like:

```
Filename                                                             PRODUCT
  07-09-18 Acknowledgement P.txt                                 ABC1
  06-22-18 Letter Req to Change.txt                              ABC2
```

Comment: can you show a sample of your input and what you expect the output to look like

Comment: I have added the sample output to the existing code. The input is the output of the `for ent in doc2.ents:
                    print(filenamez, ent.label_, ent.text)`  statement which returns a string like '10-26-18 Letter from Req - Written Resp.txt PRODUCT ABC3'
'

Comment: It's not clear what the relationship between the file name in your printed output and the filename column in the desired CSV is. Please can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `csv.writer` to write each row to the output file, using `writerow` instead of printing to the screen.

```
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\NER_training"
DIR = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\Testing\\'
print("Loading from", output_dir)
nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
with open('eng_productnames.csv', newline='') as input_file, \
        open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    writer.writerow(["Filename", "Product"])  # this is the header row
    for rowz in reader:
        try:
            filenamez = rowz[1]
            file = open(DIR+filenamez, "r", encoding ='utf-8')
            filecontentszz = file.read()
            for s in filecontentszz:
                filecontentszz = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', filecontentszz)
                #filecontents = filecontents.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
                filecontentszz = ''.join([line.lower() for line in filecontentszz]) 
                doc2 = nlp2(filecontentszz)
                for ent in doc2.ents:
                    writer.writerow([filenamez, ent.text])

                break
```

I'm assuming here that `filenamez` and `ent.text` contain the information you want in each column. If that's not the case then you can manipulate them to get what you need before writing to the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this. One that I prefer is by using Pandas, which is a powerful library to work with CSV files. 
You can create a dictionary:

```
predicted_products = {'FILENAME': [], 'PRODUCT': []}
```

and iteratively append filenames and products to the corresponding lists.

After that is done, convert predicted_products to a DataFrame, and call to_csv function:

```
import Pandas as pd
predicted_products_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(predicted_products)
predicted_products_df.to_csv('your_path/file_name.csv')
```

I prefer this way, since you can edit data easier before you save the file.

To your existing code, I suppose that `print(filenamez, ent.label_, ent.text)` prints the output. If so then:

```
import Pandas as pd
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\NER_training"
DIR = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\Testing\\'
print("Loading from", output_dir)
nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
predicted_products = {'FILENAME': [], 'PRODUCT': []}
with open('eng_productnames.csv', newline='') as myFile:
    reader = csv.reader(myFile)
    for rowz in reader:
        try:
            filenamez = rowz[1]
            file = open(DIR+filenamez, "r", encoding ='utf-8')
            filecontentszz = file.read()
            for s in filecontentszz:
                filecontentszz = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', filecontentszz)
                #filecontents = filecontents.encode().decode('unicode-escape')
                filecontentszz = ''.join([line.lower() for line in filecontentszz]) 
                doc2 = nlp2(filecontentszz)
                for ent in doc2.ents:
                    print(filenamez, ent.label_, ent.text)
                    predicted_products['FILENAME'].append(filenamez + ' ' + ent.label_)
                    predicted_products['PRODUCT'].append(ent.text)
                break

        except Exception as e:

predicted_products_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(predicted_products)
predicted_products_df.to_csv('your_path/file_name.csv')
```

Comment: But dict object is not there, it's a string. Can you edit the part in my code for better understanding